# Javascript Inheritance: Setting property of sub-class from method of super class

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Sorry if this has been asked before, but after a lot of searching, I can't seem to find an answer that definitively addresses my situation.

I have a super class that we'll call Form, which has some general methods. I'll just focus on two particular methods. `show_form()` shows the form, and `load_token()` fetches the token from the server.

## Form

```
function Form() {
  // Event handler for form submission
  this.submit_button.bind('click', jQuery.proxy(function(){
    this.submit();
  }, this));
}

Form.prototype.show_form = function() {
  // Some other stuff happens here, but this is the relevant part. 
  // We load the token
  this.load_token();
}

Form.prototype.load_token = function(){
  // Contains a synchronous ajax request that fetches the token from the server 
  // and sets it. So we end up with
  this.token = 'some-token';
};
```

Then I have a sub-class called EmailForm, which inherits from Form. I also define a custom `submit()` method for this class which is called by the event handler in `Form()`'s constructor. So I have:

## EmailForm

```
function EmailForm() {};
EmailForm.prototype = new Form();

EmailForm.prototype.submit = function() {
  console.log(this.token); // Returns undefined
};
```

Finally, here is how it all comes together

```
$('#email_form_link').bind('click', function(){
  var email_form = new EmailForm();
  email_form.show_form();
});
```

## Question

So I need the token to make a request to the server. Since several forms will be needing the `load_token()` method, I define it within the super class and have sub-classes inherit it. Since I call `email_form.show_form()`, I would expect that `email_form`'s `token` property would get set, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

So how can I call a method which was inherited from the super class, and have it change the sub-classe's properties which called it?

Comment: Are you sure that the fundamental problem isn't with an asynchronous operation not completing before the code checks for the result (the token being set)?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention. That is in fact a synchronous request.

Comment: OK, well how do you know that `.show_form()` is called before that "submit" function runs? Do you know (via `console.log()` or whatever) that `.load_token()` happens?

Comment: The form isn't visible unless the `#email_form_link` has been clicked, at which point `email_form.show_form()` is called. Therefore, unless the form has been revealed, it cannot be submitted.

Comment: isnt the `prototype` property of EmailForm() only set to a copy of the `prototype` property of Form()....so when you call email_form.show_form(), email_form doesn't have a prototype property so it checks that of Form(), and thats where the value is coming from, so it wouldnt change....

Comment: @A.O. this makes sense, but how do I get around that then?

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the methods using the `this` keyword instead of using the object's `prototype`. Of course, this means that each new object will get it's own instance of the method (more memory), instead of "inheriting" or sharing the same instance, but this way, each object (of the subclass EmailForm) will have it's own property `token` set.

Ex.

http://jsfiddle.net/64RRY/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document.

If you want a token for every form than the problem maybe is caused by asynchronous request not having returned a value when you request the value (I don't see the asynch code nor the code that request the value of token)

```
Form.prototype.load_token = function(){
  var me = this;
  $.get("ur").then(function(data){
    me.token = 'some-token';
  }//,fail function here
  );
};
```

If you want token to be set once and the value of it to be shared for every EmailForm or Form items created after that:

```
$.get("url")then(function(data){
  Form.prototype.token = data.token;
});
```